# maven xml build is getting failed

Tags: java, maven, xmlbeans

I am getting the following error while running mvn xmlbeans:xmlbeans

I m using maven version 3.5.0

D:\home\Code\abc-xmlbeans>mvn clean install

and

D:\home\Code\abc-xmlbeans>mvn castor:generate

is working fine
The only problem is the following error:

```
D:\home\Code\abc-xmlbeans>mvn xmlbeans:xmlbeans
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building WBILL XMLBEANS 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- xmlbeans-maven-plugin:2.3.3:xmlbeans (default-cli) @ abc-xmlbeans ---
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:\home\Code\abc-xmlbeans\javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "D:\home\Code\abc-xmlbeans\javac": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.CodeGenUtil.externalCompile(CodeGenUtil.java:231)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaCompiler.compile(SchemaCompiler.java:1154)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.xmlbeans.AbstractXmlBeansPlugin.execute(AbstractXmlBeansPlugin.java:280)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 28 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.688 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-11T16:52:57+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/212M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:xmlbeans-maven-plugin:2.3.3:xmlbeans (default-cli) on project abc-xmlbeans: XmlBeans compile failed:
[ERROR]  xml ErrorLoading schema file D:\home\Code\abc-xmlbeans\src\main\xsd\List1.xsd
[ERROR] xml ErrorLoading schema file D:\home\Code\abc-xmlbeans\src\main\xsd\List2.xsd
[ERROR] xml ErrorLoading schema file D:\home\Code\abc-xmlbeans\src\main\xsd\List3.xsd
[ERROR] xml ErrorLoading schema file D:\home\Code\abc-xmlbeans\src\main\xsd\List4.xsd
[ERROR] xml ErrorLoading schema file D:\home\Code\abc-xmlbeans\src\main\xsd\List5.xsd
[ERROR] xml ErrorLoading schema file D:\home\Code\abc-xmlbeans\src\main\xsd\List6.xsd
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Can anyone help me in fixing this issue?

Thanks
Izaz

Comment: Well apparently the psd files aren't in the location you specified.

Comment: those all files are present there

Comment: Not according to the error... I suspect the error to be correct... So your files aren't in the location you expect them to be.

Comment: Looks like it is tryin to find the compiler "javac" at the location ""D:\home\Code\abc-xmlbeans\javac" which I assume is incorrect ?

Comment: @mkane.. I also think so.. but how to fix that

Comment: Check your system env variables and verify java path

Answer (score 1):

Go to your pom.xml and contained therein will be the definition information for the xmlbeans-maven-plugin .

Simply add configuration to it's definition:

```
<configuration>

                <compiler>Path to your javac.exe....</compiler>
</configuration>
```

Comment: when i added this I got the following error which is quite similar
`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin": CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)`

Comment: The path you configure should include the javac.exe i.e. <configuration>

                <compiler>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\javac.exe</compiler>
</configuration>

Comment: thanks it worked. But the issue is same. After that i need to create a ear file by "mvn clean install". It is giving the following error again
`[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\\Code\abc-logger\target\classes
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] abc    SUCCESS [  0.470 s]
[INFO] abc LOGGER  FAILURE [  1.017 s]
[INFO] abc CASTOR  SKIPPED
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE`

Comment: That is a different error you are seeing now. What path did you place to the javac. Make sure it not a JRE path . It should be a JDK path as noted in the new error you have attached...

Comment: after setting the path also, getting the same error

Comment: What did you enter for the <compiler> path ? Ensure that a javac.exe exists at the location. You should not get the same error if you are pointing at a JDK javac.exe.

Comment: what is think is mvn is not able to fine javac ? but i am not able to get why

Comment: That is exactly what seems to be occurring and why I suggested you enter the xmlbeans-maven-plugin configuration entries. Can you post your complete entry from the pom.xml for the xmlbeans-maven-plugin . You should verify that the entry you have for the compiler actually exists.

Comment: As per recent comments access is denied error coming. Better set java environment variables at system level. I wonder what are you getting at `mvn -version` ?